# Calculating $\int\int _{[0,1]\times[0,1] }xy d(x,y)$ from definition

Tags: integration

How can I calculate $\int\int _{[0,1]\times[0,1] }xy d(x,y)$ from definition (without Fubini).

---

We know that this integral exists, since $f(x)=xy$ is continuous on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

So for any choice of intermediate points $S$ and any partition $P$ of unit square which mesh is going to $0$ the limit of Riemannian sum must be the same, thus I can choose arbitrary $P$ and $S$.

Let $P_n=\{[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}]\times [\frac{l}{n},\frac{l+1}{n}] \mbox{ , } k,l=0\dots n-1\}$. Also, I chose the following set of intermediate points: $S_n=\{(\frac{k}{n},\frac{l}{n}) \mbox{ , }k, l=0\dots n-1\}\}$.

Now I have to calculate the limit:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sum_{l=0}^{n-1} \frac{kl}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{n^2}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  \frac{k}{n} \sum_{l=0}^{n-1} \frac{l}{n} \right)=\frac{1}{4}$$

Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.**

For $n\ge 1$ integer you have $$1+2+\dots +n=\sum_{k=1}^n k =\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Hence your sum tends to $\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 2):

A hint:

The situation is a cartesian product in all respects, and so is your last double sum.

Answer (score 2):

Another hint: It is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sum_{l=0}^{n-1} \frac{kl}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{n^2}
= \frac1{n^3}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k\right)\cdot\left( \sum_{l=0}^{n-1} l\right)$$